# nginx reverse http proxy not caching php-generated images

Tags: nginx, php, cache

I'm testing creating a cache in nginx and have it working great under both directories I have set up except the following:  When I try to cache a php-generated image, it simply acts as a proxy to my apache server running the php image-generation script.  It works fine on any static html, css, js, or text files.  How can I get nginx to cache the php-generated images too?  I'm thinking something might be missing from my PHP generation to make nginx think its a cacheable file, but not sure where to go from here.

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
  proxy_cache_path  /var/www/cache/muncherelli/cdn levels=1:2 keys_zone=muncherelli:8m max_size=1000m inactive=600m;
  proxy_cache_path  /var/www/cache/mi/client/images levels=1:2 keys_zone=miclient:8m max_size=1000m inactive=600m;
  proxy_temp_path /var/www/cache/tmp;


  server {
    location /muncherelli/cdn/ {
      proxy_pass http://muncherelli.com/wp-content/;
      proxy_cache muncherelli;
      proxy_cache_valid  200 302  60m;
      proxy_cache_valid  404      1m;
    }

    location /mi/client/images/ {
      proxy_pass http://client.images.example.com/;
      proxy_cache miclient;
      proxy_cache_valid  200 302  60m;
      proxy_cache_valid  404      1m;
    }
  }

}
```

and the image creation part of my php script:

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($full_image_path);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

How do I get nginx to cache these images as well?

Comment: What are the full HTTP headers output from your PHP script to nginx?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen, looks like I goofed.  Checked the header and found a stray
Set-Cookie:·fileDownload=true;·path=/
in the header.  Removed that and we are caching away!  Feel free to answer the question looking into headers and I'll give you the point.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely some extra header is preventing nginx from caching the response.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue.  I found a lingering set cookie in the HTTP headers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to add my answer too, I was debugging for 2 weeks (true unfortunately).

> php pages (or others) that have `setcookie()` are NOT cached by
>   default in nginx cache / reverse proxy.

I had a cookie "login_return_url" on each listing details pages (over 500 000) and I didn't understand why site seems slower and gets less and less traffic and google hits despite the caching that apparently worked fine.

And I was mostly logged in (no login return cookie needed) so I got cached pages while everyone else didn't.

Thank you @muncherelli !